# PDF in webview Android 6.0

Tags: android

I am trying to load pdf file from link in Android Marshmallow. It always shows blank screen while the code works fine with lower versions than 6.0. Please help.
Thanks

Below is code which i am using

```
webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                webView.loadUrl ("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url="+url);
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               // showProgress(LoadPageByUrlActivity.this,"Please wait...");
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
            {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
               // stopProgress();
            }
        });
        String url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("url");
        if(url.contains("pdf")){
            webView.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url="+url);
        }else
            webView.loadUrl(url);
    }
```

Comment: We cannot help you with code that we cannot see. Please edit your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: My simple question is, how to load a PDF file from link in Android 6.0 onward?

Comment: What is the value of `getIntent().getExtras().getString("url")`? Please understand that you are relying on Google Drive, and there is no requirement that they support that `drive.google.com` URL indefinitely, for arbitrary PDFs, and for arbitrary versions of `WebView` (let alone other browsers).